# C: when doesn't work with list values in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, if-statement, jstl

Below is the code, `In quentionAnsers[0]` in have's single as string value, When i display **${quentionAnsers[0]}** it prints single in the same page but it is not working with c:when, In my Jsp page i'm getting both check box and, radio button where i'm expecting only checkbox's. Please help me!

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html> 
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="mainbody">

        <H4>Please answer the following quetions</H4>
        <form method="post" action="demoServlet">
            <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>${quentionAnsers[1]}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><c:set var="questionAnswers" value="${quentionAnsers[0]}" />
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${questionAnswers == 'single'}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="English" />English
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="French" />French
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female</td>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
         </div>
       </div>
       </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import the jstl tag library in the top of your page :

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

This is the new code :

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <html> 
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="mainbody">

        <H4>Please answer the following quetions</H4>
        <form method="post" action="demoServlet">
            <table cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <td>${quentionAnsers[1]}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${quentionAnsers[0] == 'single'}">
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="English" />English
                                <input type="checkbox" name="language" value="French" />French
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" />Male
                                <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" />Female</td>
                        </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>
                    </td>

                </tr>

            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
         </div>
       </div>
       </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: In Expression Language you can just use the == or eq operator to compare object values.

Comment: even that is not working, I added full page please have a look.

Comment: Check my new answer. Add the library jstl core. It works for me, so normally its ok.

Comment: It's weird to not have an error on jsp page if he's missing import of the taglib!

Comment: That's what i am missing, Thank you for pointing. strange it dint trowed me any error.

Answer (score 0):

if it prints single without extra whitespace

your test should be like your code == or eq

```
<c:when test="${quentionAnsers[0] == 'single'}">
```

It's weird if you have both checkboxes and radiobuttons!

Comment: its s not an capital one, its an typo in the quetion.

Comment: How do you print the value in your jsp? make sure there's no white space!

Comment: I don't have white space.